# nsurlsessiond - taking up all bandwidth

Tags: macos, macos-mojave, bandwidth

[image]

I am trying to find a solution to prevent `nsurlsessiond` using up all my bandwidth. It is using 2GB of data daily. I have also tried the links below. Because of this issue I am not able to complete my company work. Please can anyone help?

1. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/nsurlsessiond-heavy-network-usage.2027130/
2. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/nsurlsessiond-process-going-crazy-on-catalina.2228994/
3. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/nsurlsessiond-downloading-data.1785204/
4. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6605949

I am getting this while on click `nsurlsessiond`.

[image]

Comment: Does it stop using bandwidth if you shut down the simulator?

Comment: @PhillipMills, no it's not stoping

Comment: Check this url: https://www.swiftdevcenter.com/nsurlsessiond-keep-downloading-and-consuming-all-bandwidth-xcode/

Comment: If mac user - disable automatic downloads of Podcasts in the Apple Podcasts app. You're welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 31):

I fix it by disabling Software Updates.

Go to System Preferences -> Software Update

Click on Advanced... and uncheck "Check for Updates"

[image]

**Edit**

I had this issue again recently but only when i opened the iOS simulator. I don't know what's the problem but the simulator will use internet for about 500MB and back to normal.
Either you can wait until simulator stops downloading or just block the url using firewall as @Lutze explained

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO :)

Comment: I spent several days and tried different approaches. But only this answer helped. Thanks you!

Comment: Thanks for helping. I was visiting a new country where data rates are 20x more expensive. My mac was simply drinking all the data like a smoothie and my head was like 

Comment: thanks a lot! mac calm down after I turn it off

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that any application can delegate transfers to the NSURLSession Daemon. As a workaround you could use an application firewall like [Little snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index-de.html) to detect and block the specific domain where the traffic comes from.

In my case it was "osxapps.itunes.apple.com" that took a lot of bandwidth.

[Screenshot of little snitch with the blocked domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhBAr.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**Best Solution:**

You can create a script that runs whenever `nsurlsessiond` is created and stops it automatically, you can use `launchd`, a built-in system service on macOS that manages processes and runs scripts at specific intervals or in response to specific events.

Here are the steps to create a `launchd` script that monitors `nsurlsessiond` and stops it automatically:

1- Open the Terminal application on your MacBook.

2- Create a new `launchd` configuration file by running the following command:

```js
nano ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.nsurlsessiond-monitor.plist
```

This will open the nano text editor and create a new file named `com.example.nsurlsessiond-monitor.plist` in the LaunchAgents directory.

3- Paste the following XML code into the nano text editor:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.example.nsurlsessiond-monitor</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/bin/bash</string>
      <string>-c</string>
      <string>while true; do
          if pgrep nsurlsessiond > /dev/null; then
            killall nsurlsessiond
          fi
          sleep 5
        done</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <dict>
      <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
      <false/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

This code defines a `launchd` configuration file that runs a bash script that checks if `nsurlsessiond` is running every 5 seconds and stops it if it is. The `KeepAlive` key ensures that the script is always running, and the `SuccessfulExit` key ensures that the script is restarted if it exits with an error.

4- Save the file and exit nano by pressing `Control+O`, then `Enter`, and then `Control+X`.

5- Load the `launchd` configuration file by running the following command:

```js
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.nsurlsessiond-monitor.plist
```

This will register the `launchd` job and start running the script.

Now, whenever `nsurlsessiond` is created, the script will automatically stop it. If you want to stop the script manually, you can unload the `launchd` configuration file by running the following command:

```js
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.nsurlsessiond-monitor.plist
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, then I fixed using this way:

***System Settings > Apple ID > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Turn Off***

**Important:** After this process, your data may not be synchronized with iCloud.

[image: iCloud Settings]

Answer (score 0):

```
launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plist
sudo launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.nsurlstoraged.plist
```

This works for me.

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue for a couple of days - i installed 11.3.1 which had been pending for a while and the issue seems to have sorted itself out.

Answer (score 0):

if *Nsurlsessiond Causes High CPU and Bandwidth Usage* , do this :

1 - Go to **Activity Monitor**, and locate the `trustd` process.

2 - Copy its **PID** from the **PID column**.

3 - Launch Terminal and run the `# sudo kill -9 [trustd PID]` command to end the parent trustd process.

```
Note: Replace [trustd PID] with the PID you just copied.
```

4 - Run the `# ls -la /var/folders/zz | grep nsurlsessiond` command to find the **specific “randomized name”** directory. You’re going to need this information for the next command.

5 - Then, run the `# sudo rm -fr /var/folders/zz/[randomized name]` command to remove the nsurlsessiond temporary directory.

```
Note: Replace [randomized name] with the name you previously found.
```

[source](https://appletoolbox.com/nsurlsessiond-high-cpu-bandwidth-usage/)

---

6 - follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65963919/1367344)

Answer (score -2):

i used  ***`cloudfare Warp`***  App and it stopped the  *nsurlsessiond*   from downloading .

ITS WORKING  for me on MacBookPro using Big sur OS :)