# On Starting mac and running xcode simulator Consume around 500MB Internet Data

Tags: macos, ios-simulator, macos-catalina, xcode11

For Past 4 week i observer when i run my Xcode application on simulator on first time simulator launch it consume around 500MB internet data.
This is not project specific issue. Every time when i shutdown and start the mac and run Xcode as soon as simulator open it will consume same amount of Data.
Can any one help me What is the issue?? or any background service run??

Xcode version: 11.6 (11E708)

simulator: 13.6

OSX: 10.15.6

Please help me **unnecessary every time my Internet Data is consume i have to fix this**

This issue is still persist after updating to **xcode 11.7**

Comment: Have you tried fully resetting the simulator? You can do this by going to `Device` on the toolbar and selecting `Erase all content and settings...`

Comment: can you confirm that it's not your application code that is responsible for the data consumption?

Comment: yes i verify its not related to my code. even i shutdown my mac . start it and create a new project. as soon as my simulator is loaded it start consuming my internet data

Comment: Did you try using a tool such as Wireshark or Burp to see where is the data going to/from  and what is downloaded or sent ? It could help figuring things out

Comment: @Youri ok i will check

Comment: This question is more appropriate for https://apple.stackexchange.com/, not in SO. There you will find more users, looking for questions/answers about Apple. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nsurlsessiond - taking up all bandwidth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098280/nsurlsessiond-taking-up-all-bandwidth)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks For @Rado for suggesting the https://apple.stackexchange.com/.
After posting the question on https://apple.stackexchange.com/  i fond the answer.

**Orginal Answer:** [Xcode simulator constantly download something](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/377220/xcode-simulator-constantly-download-something)

**Answer:**
rename the file com.apple.nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/

to something -com.apple.nsurlsessiond

and also the file nsurlsessiond(Dont delete) in

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/libexec/

to something -nsurlsessiond

Apps with admob works perfectly also no problem with safari

Comment: Thanks. you saved me a stream of consumed data :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need an internet connection for testing you application, you could simply disable the network.

Comment: I need a internet connection to run my app. I thing in OSX Level some setting is enable which cause this problem.

Comment: This answer made me laugh :)
Cut the lan cord to enable firewall right? :D

Answer (score 0):

You could run wireshark and see what it is actually doing, or at least see where it is connecting to.

Answer (score 0):

I used tripmode firewall don't give simulator internet access only give when you need it.

Works fine but when you forget to turn it off and start the simulator next time, you feel horrible :(